# Find out percentage on basis of occurence of same combination bigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

```
name             id
--------------------
ramesh           1
sonali           1
yash             2
garima           3
dipti            3
vashali          4
karishma         5
ramesh           6
sonali           6
--------------------

output:
name1 with name2 %
--------------------------------
ramesh      sonali      66.66%  
garima      Dipti       16.66%
```

Comment: name followed by their id

Comment: I edited the question for formatting, but I'm not sure what you are asking. What's the difference between name1 and name2, and what would happen if there is a name3?

Comment: @RameshPatel - would be great to understand how you ended up with 66.66% and 16.66% for above example. i dont see any logic that can end up with such numbers for this example

Comment: @ Mikhail Berlyant- I want to count the no. of combinations of 2 names which come together with same id and then get the percentage of it from total records(group by id)  . As In my query I gave the example, ramesh and sonali come together 2 times with same id as first with id=1 and secondly with id=6. then the percentage of their combination is calculated as (no. of times combination occur together/total no.of unique id )*100  --------- (2/6)*100=66.66%

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get - but the question is not very clear:

```
SELECT names, 100*ratio percent
FROM (
  SELECT names, COUNT(*) c, FIRST(names_c) names_c, RATIO_TO_REPORT(c) OVER() ratio
  FROM (
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(UNIQUE(name)) names, COUNT(*) names_c
    FROM 
    (SELECT 1 id, 'ramesh' name),
    (SELECT 1 id, 'sonali' name),
    (SELECT 2 id, 'rash' name),
    (SELECT 3 id, 'garima' name),
    (SELECT 3 id, 'dipti' name),
    (SELECT 4 id, 'vashali' name),
    (SELECT 5 id, 'karishma' name),
    (SELECT 6 id, 'ramesh' name),
    (SELECT 6 id, 'sonali' name),
    GROUP BY 1
  ) 
  GROUP BY names
)
WHERE names_c>1
```